# С# перенаправление вывода с консоли на форму

Tags: c#, консоль, форма, вывод

В проекте на С# вызываю асинхронно (в отдельном потоке, через  Process) консольное приложение, написанное на С++. Перенаправляю вывод в RichTextBox. Выводится все после завершения процесса, а нужно чтоб при появлении новой строки в консоли, сразу  выводилось в том же RichTextBox.
В чем может быть причина задержки вывода?
Тоже самое делаю с вызовом консольного приложения, написанного на С#, выводится одновременно с консолью.
Класс для запуска процесса

```
    class PSRunner
    {
        public event DataReceivedEventHandler ChildProcessEventHandler;
        public PSRunner()
        { }
        public int Run(string psname, string arguments)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = psname;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            //отключаем использование оболочки, чтобы можно было читать данные вывода
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            //перенаправляем данные вывода
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            //задаем кодировку, чтобы читать кириллические символы
            p.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
            //запрещаем создавать окно для запускаемой программы
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;// false;
            //подписываемся на событие, которые возвращает данные

            p.OutputDataReceived += //new DataReceivedEventHandler(Start.DescriptionCallBack(e.Data + "\n"));
                (o, e) =>
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                {
                    if (ChildProcessEventHandler != null)
                    {
                        ChildProcessEventHandler(o, e);
                    }
                }
            };

            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            //включаем возможность определять когда происходит выход из программы, которую будем запускать      
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;///

            p.Start();
            // p.BeginErrorReadLine();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            p.WaitForExit();
            return p.ExitCode;
        }
    }
```

Запуск процессов

```
class Start
    {
        public delegate void description(string sDescription);
        /// <summary>   </summary>
        public static event description DescriptionCallBack;

        public delegate void errorDescription(string sErrorDescription);
        public delegate void endDescription();

        /// <summary>    </summary>
        public static event errorDescription errorDescriptionCallBack;
        /// <summary>   </summary>
        public static event endDescription endDescriptionCallBack;
        public static void start(int k)
        {
            try
            {
                int rez = -1;
                PSRunner psr = new PSRunner();
                psr.ChildProcessEventHandler += (o, e) => DescriptionCallBack(e.Data + "\n");
                rez = psr.Run("ConsoleApplicationS++.exe", k.ToString());
                if (rez != 0)
                {
                    errorDescriptionCallBack("Помилка!" + rez);
                    return;
                }
                rez = psr.Run("ConsoleApplication1.exe", k.ToString());///Сшарп
                if (rez != 0)
                {
                    errorDescriptionCallBack("Помилка!" + rez);
                    return;
                }
                endDescriptionCallBack();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorDescriptionCallBack(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
```

ВЫЗОВ

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public delegate void dGUI();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Start.errorDescriptionCallBack += StartUpError;//
           Start.endDescriptionCallBack += StartUpEnd;
           Start.DescriptionCallBack += Description;

           int k = int.Parse(textBoxDisk.Text);//15;
           new Thread(() => Start.start(k)).Start();
        }

        private void Description(string sRec)
        {
            Invoke(new dGUI(delegate ()
            { 
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(sRec);

            }));
        }

        private void StartUpError(string s)
        {
            Start.errorDescriptionCallBack -= StartUpError;
            Start.DescriptionCallBack -= Description;
            Start.endDescriptionCallBack -= StartUpEnd;
            MessageBox.Show(s, "Помилка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

        private void StartUpEnd()
        {
            Start.errorDescriptionCallBack -= StartUpError;
            Start.DescriptionCallBack -= Description;
            Start.endDescriptionCallBack -= StartUpEnd;
            MessageBox.Show( "Конец!");
        }

    }
```

Пример консольного з задержками времени

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int count  = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    int u32Bytes = 0, iFileBytes = 0;
    fprintf(stdout, "StartC++!!");
    for(int i=0;i<count; i++)
    {
        u32Bytes++;
        iFileBytes +=5;
        Sleep(1000);
        double qwe = 100-(double)u32Bytes;//*100
        fprintf(stdout, "\rDownloading %.2f%%", 100-(double)u32Bytes);

    }
    //_getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос по С#, так как вызывающий проект написан на С#.

Comment: *Тоже самое делаю с вызовом консольного приложения, написанного на С#, выводится одновременно с консолью.* - а должно как выводится?

Comment: С вызовом  консольного приложения, написанного на С#, все нормально. Проблема с вызовом  консольного приложения, написанного на С++, все выводится только после завершения вызова, а нужно в процессе.

Comment: Вы не опубликовали код с++ приложения, допускаю что это накладно. Возможно и не надо. А может с++ приложение выводит одним куском? Хорошо. `cmd.exe` написано на с++, согланы? Приложение `cmd.exe /C timeout 10` - выполняется из под вашей программы правильно, или не правильно (итоговый текст)?

Comment: cmd.exe /C timeout 10 Выполняется без задержек времени.    В вопрос добавила пример приложения с задержками  времени

Comment: Если отключить буферизацию в вызываемом приложении при помощи fflush(stdout), то вывод выполняется без задержек времени. Можно ли отключить буферизацию в вызывающем приложении?

Comment: Условно да. Если вы делаете редирект через `pipe` то у вас будет копия хандла  stdout в руках, и вы можете хоть раз в секунуду его flush делать, а может и проблемы не будет соовсем. Поищите реализацию через pipe в сети. Попробуйте из  `p.StartInfo` достать хандл -  думаю в с# через `pipe` реализовано.